# Serving a static HTML page containing an image using Node JS / Express

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I am able to serve static HTML pages using express. I also installed "ejs" to render the page with data from local variables in my .js file. I just need to display a small logo in the corner of the page along with the rest of the data.
Opening just the html file in the browser loads the image just fine, but with the server I get  a broken image. I think it may be a problem with my file path or directory structure.
Here is my original simple code without the futile attempts:

**server.js**

```
var express = require ('express');
var fs = require ('fs');
var app = express ();
var bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
app.use (bodyParser ());
var server = require ('http').createServer (app);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);

var my_name="Goku";
var my_power=9001;

app.get ('/', function (req, res){
    console.log ('GET /');
    res.render('index.html',{name:my_name,power:my_power});    
    });

server.listen (8888);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<input id="name" value=" <%=name%> " /><br>
<input id="power" value=" <%=power%> "/><br>
</body>
</html>
```

I have not included the img src line so that you can give me the complete line, people overlook my subtle syntax errors sometimes.Regarding directory structure, I just have this 'server.js' file in my /home folder and the 'index.html' file in /home/views

---

Solution offered by Ploutch:
I moved the logo.jpg to a '/images' folder I created under '/home'
I just added these lines -

**server.js**

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
```

**index.html**

```
<img src="/logo.jpg" />
```

Since I am using ejs to render the page with local variables, if I place the logo.jpg in the  current directory instead of a separate images folder, the image loads fine but the output of "name" and "power" will be broken.

Comment: So much var, it hurt. Could you post the ejs file too?

Comment: ejs file? Is that the same as the "index.html" file ?

Comment: In your case, yes, and that may be your error, edit your question and add your index.html

Comment: Added. You think the extension may be the problem ?
Oh, I think we only need to worry about the app.set and app.engine statements. The others are all standard in most programs.

Comment: May be yes, try to change it. What I first thought was that you didn t used a ejs file at all. But does it display Goku and 9001 correctly?

Comment: But the code I pasted works nicely without the extension. It's just the image that is broken. Do you have any advice about the directory structure (i.e where to place the image file) and the file path(just 'logo.jpg' or the complete 'file:///home/logo.jpg') ?

Comment: The actual program is a lot bigger and even that works nicely. I just don't know why the image is broken even in this small code.

Comment: If I understand html doc, it should be the public url of the image, but I don t know how to know this. It could be 'file:///home/logo.jpg', or whatever url return the image (exemple https://startpage.com/s/black/graphics/startpage_logo_res.png)

Comment: Renaming to .ejs does not help, and neither file path I mentioned works for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to serve your resource files (images, js, css, ...) in a static way.

To do this, put them in a subdirectory, then add this before `server.listen`

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

(Assuming `public` is the name of the folder containing your static files)

Then, assuming your picture is called `logo.png` you can call it like this :

```
<img src="/logo.png" />
```