# External js in an EJS template

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, ejs

I have some trouble using EJS. I would like to use a javascript file in my template, but I can't find the right way to implement it, here is my code so far :

game.ejs :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>D-D-D-Duel !!!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/view/css/game.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src= "/actions_client.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
    ...
        </style>
    // My body
    </body>
</html>
```

Whatever path I try for my script /actions_client.js, the view can't find it while loading in my browser. It's maybe a problem with node.js I also use, I don't know where to put my script in order to make my view find it (what and/or where is the folder localhost:8080/ ?)

Regards

EDIT : Something that I don't understand neither is how can the view find socket.io/socket.io/js while I don't find it when I search on my computer ?

EDIT : Here is my code in my node file by the way :

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(), 
server = require('http').createServer(app), 
io = require('socket.io').listen(server), 
fs = require('fs'), 
composants = require('./modules_persos/composants');
```

Comment: Regarding your edit: `socket.io.js` will be within `node_packages`, possibly a few levels down, [under `socket.io-client`](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client).

Comment: "*It's maybe a problem with node.js I also use*" Have you define the `http.Server` in Node to serve static files like `actions_client.js`? If so, can you share that snippet of the code? If not, can you provide some basics about the server's definition -- are you using any libraries or frameworks?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013675/serving-a-static-html-page-containing-an-image-using-node-js-express?noredirect=1#comment40744871_26013675

Comment: I've actually found `socket.io.js` under `socket.io-client`, thanks. I haven't done anything about static files actually, here is my code :

`var express = require('express');
var app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
fs = require('fs'),
composants = require('./modules_persos/composants');`

Comment: @Kahsius: You should edit your question and put your code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/ressources'));
```

to set the 'localhost:8080' folder as ./ressource.

__dirname is automatically generated by nodejs and contain the filepath to the folder in which is stored your node.js script.

However, `/socket.io/socket.io.js` will be in `__dirname + '/socket.io/socket.io.js'`.

Answer (score 3):

In express app.js file you just use

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Then you can add external script in public folder or online link of js file in ejs template. like as

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I thinks that is helpful for you.
You also can see [Here](http://www.initcode.info/ejshtml_not_finding_external_js_file_node_js)