# How to get relative image path on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js, I want to return a page, that has a relative link to an image path.
In the server I have `server.js` and `images.jpg` in the same folder. I ran the server, and when I visit the server link, it returns this html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
<img src="images.jpg"/>
</body>

</html>
```

But the image is not loading. How can I get the correct relative link?

Thanks

Comment: How do you serve static files? What do you get when you visit images.jpg directly in browser?

Comment: I dont know how to serve it, nothing happens when I visit `localhost:41302/images.jpg`.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013675/serving-a-static-html-page-containing-an-image-using-node-js-express

Comment: Putting this file in the same folder will not make it automagically served.

Comment: we need to see your code to know what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Your node.js server does not serve ANY images or files by default (this may be different than some other web servers).  If you want it to serve a URL that is `images.jpg`, then you need to create a route/handler in your http server so that when that image is requested, the appropriate image data is returned.

If you show us your server code and show us the code that serves this particular page (so we know what path will come with `images.jpg`) and explain where in your file system that image is located, we could advise how to modify your node.js server so that it will serve this image.

If using Express with node.js, you can [serve static files](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) on a particular path with one line of code, but we need the above info to know more explicitly what to recommend.