# How to read image from HTML file with NodeJS?

Tags: html, node.js, readfile

I want to read an HTML file.

[image]

My HTML content:

```
<html>
  <hear>
    <title>Learn NodeJS</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <center>
      <h1>Learn NodeJS with Khuong Pham</h1>
      <img width="400" src="/nodejs.png" />
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried:

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const folderPath = __dirname + '/public_files'

app.use(express.static(folderPath))

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var filePath = folderPath + '/index.html'
  console.log(filePath)

  fs.access(filePath, fs.F_OK | fs.R_OK, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      response.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type' : 'text/html' })
      response.end('<h1>File not found</h1>')
    } else {
      fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, contentFile){
        if (!err) {
          response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type' : 'text/html' })
          response.end(contentFile)
        } else {
          response.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type' : 'text/html' })
          response.end('<h1>Can not read this content</h1>')
        }
      })
    }
  })
}).listen(3500)
```

But when I access `http://localhost:3500/`, it says:

[image]

Comment: If you change this line `response.end(contentFile)` by these: `response.write(contentFile); response.end();` does it work?

Comment: It still has the same problem.

Comment: Please add this before the `console.log(filePath)` line: `console.log(baseURI.pathName)`. What's the result?

Comment: Hi @RicardoPontual, it prints `undefined`

Comment: That's the problem. Try to set the filePath like this for a test: `var filePath=folderPath + '/index.html'`

Comment: @RicardoPontual, it will work, but the image won't load.

Comment: You need to change the image path in the html file, or inform nodejs that it will serve the files from a specific path, this answer shows how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26015375/4730201

Comment: Hi @RicardoPontual, I've tried this, but didn't work, please check my update code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two methods here. Firstly you are trying to use `express`, but later you are starting your own server using `http.createServer` Instead you should use `express` to do so.

Your `js` should be something similar to below. Have not tested below code. Edit it approiately. This is just to show the idea.

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const folderPath = __dirname + '/public_files'

//mount your static paths
// renders your image and index.html
app.use(express.static(folderPath))

// renders your index.html
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

//mount your other paths
// in this case render 404.
app.get("*",function (req, res) {
  res.status(404).send(''<h1>File not found</h1>'');
});

//start the server.
app.listen(3500, function () {
 console.log('Example app listening on port 3500!');
});
```