# Why doesn't the template handlebars see or parse the url of the img tag?

Tags: javascript, image, templates, handlebars.js

My template:

```
// object.handlebars
<section>
        <h1 class="object-title">{{ title }}</h1>
        <div class="swiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                {{#each url}}
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="image-slider_image">
                                <img class="slider-img" src={{this}} alt="Фото" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

My json:

```
// data.json
{
   "2": {
        "title": "Поточний (аварійний) ремонт підвального приміщення Мистецького ліцею «Зміна» під облаштування найпростішого укриття",
        "url": ["./images/Shelters/photo_1.jpg", "./images/Shelters/photo_2.jpg", "./images/Shelters/photo_3.jpg", "./images/Shelters/photo_4.jpg", "./images/Shelters/photo_5.jpg", "./images/Shelters/photo_6.jpg"],
        "place": "Мистецький ліцей «Зміна» Дніпровського району м. Києва",
        "kindOfWork": "Ремонт підвального приміщення під укриття для дитячого ліцею"
    }
}
```

Function in index.js

```
const pointEntry = document.querySelector('.pointEntry');
import dataJson from '../data.json' assert {type: 'json'};
import objectTpl from '../templates/object.handlebars';

function searchDataObject(objectId) {
    const markup = objectTpl(dataJson[objectId]);
    pointEntry.innerHTML = '';
    pointEntry.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', markup);
};
```

Project structure:

```
src {
      images {
               Shelters {
                          photo_1.jpg, photo_2.jpg, ...
                        }
               ...
              }
      templates {
                  object.handlebars
                }
      js {
           index.js
         }
      index.html
      portfolio.html (pointEntry is here)
}
```

Template come to portfolio.html, all is well with text (title and other), and the way come to portfolio.html, but the image is not displayed in the browser.

I tried to insert a picture with an absolute path - it didn't work, I changed the path in data.json to: "../images/Shelters/photo_1.jpg" (like from template object.handlebars), I put other quotes: {{{url}}} - it didn't work, I tried this `src = "{{url}}"` - it didnt work. In console I see this `<img class="slider-img" src="./images/Shelters/photo_1.jpg" alt="Фото"/>`, but the image still is not displayed in the browser.
What is the problem?

Comment: Most likely it has to do with your image paths and you should start them with `/` instead of `./`. For an explanation, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741846/3397771

Comment: "but the image is not displayed in the browser" — Are you saying that the problem is not that Handlebars fails to put the URL into the `src` attribute, but that the URL you used doesn't result in the image displaying? If so, you should focus the question on that and not muddy the waters with handlebars. Show the HTML output instead of the JS + handlebars template.

Comment: Use the Network tab if your browser's developer tools to debug the problem. Look at the URLs being requested for the images. Look at the response you get (is it a 200 OK? a 404 Not Found? Something else?)

Comment: @76484 It still doesn`t work

Comment: @Quentin Status 200 OK, image is not displayed in the browser only in handlebars template, other images in my project are displayed.
the HTML output:

Comment: @Quentin
`
<section>
      <h1 class="object-title">Поточний (аварійний) ремонт підвального приміщення Мистецького ліцею «Зміна» під облаштування найпростішого укриття</h1>
        <div class="swiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="image-slider_image">
                                <img class="slider-img" src="/images/Shelters/photo_1.jpg" alt="Фото">
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
           ...
        </div>
    </section>
`

Comment: @Quentin Status 200 OK for photo_1.jpg

Comment: I don't understand how the image request can get a 200 response and yet the image does not show. This would suggest you are hiding the image with CSS.

Comment: @76484 I see a broken image icon on the screen. Maybe It can be problem with parcel?

Comment: If you see a broken image then I don't believe that you are getting a 200 response for that image. I believe that the image path must be wrong and that the request returns a 404. This would not be due to Parcel, but due to an incorrect image path.

Comment: @76484 in Network for photo_1.jpeg: Status 200 OK, Content-Type: text/html, initiator: index.js. It isn`t loaded like img

Comment: `Content-Type: text/html` certainly isn't the expected header. This suggests the problem is how you are serving images and has nothing to do with HTML or Handlebars. This would be due to how you have configured your server application to serve static content.

Comment: @76484 Okay, thank you for your time, I will think about it and write how I solve the problem

Comment: Maybe this post can be of some help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26015375/3397771